# Paintable wood sealer - does this exist

Tags: wood, paint, sealing, staining, stain

I have ground contact (MCA) wood which has dried for some number of weeks.  I was thinking of sealing it to maximize exterior lifetime over many years and was wondering if there is a type of sealer which is paintable in case I later decide I want to paint the wood a certain color instead.

I looked online and it seems like this may not be a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it would depend what you consider to be a "sealer" - you could epoxy coat it (and then you'd need spar varnish or something like that over the top for UV damage prevention) and that can be sanded and painted when/if desired. Or you could head straight for the spar varnish.

"Deck Seal Products" - probably not, most are some form of silicone oil or wax that's incompatible with paint.

If the wood is properly treated for ground contact, the difference in lifetime will be minimal. And the same holds true if it's not properly treated for ground contact, just the timeframe is a lot shorter.

Comment: Good to know - thanks.  Does your note about difference in lifetime refer to just structural integrity or to things like splintering / texture?